# $X_1$,$X_2$....$X_n$ are iid N($\mu,\sigma^2$). Derive a confidence interval for the parametric function $\mu+\sigma$ and $\mu/\sigma$.

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

I know how to find confidence interval for each of the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ but don't know how to find in the case of parametric function.

Comment: Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Later asked here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/382124/x-1-x-2-dots-x-n-overset-textiid-sim-n-mu-sigma2-derive-a-confide.